# Display post date as 04/26/2013

Tags: date

I want to modify the date display of the post entries from current format:

April 26, 2013

to this:

04/26/2013

Where in the code can I make this change?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_time( 'm/d/Y' );
```

or

```
the_date( 'm/d/Y' );
```

Note, `the_date()` will not print the same value twice. If a second post would get the same output you get nothing.

If your theme doesn’t set a fixed value, like Twenty Twelve …

```
get_the_date()
```

… then the format is taken from your settings in *Settings/General Settings*:

[image]

You can change the format here, no need to change the theme.

Comment: Thanks! - But where should I make that change, @toscho?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov Where these functions are used in your theme and you want to change the output. I don’t know the theme, so I cannot be more specific. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. It's TwentyTwelve, @toscho!

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the post date format in `Settings > General`
Under `Date Format` the third option down for `mm/dd/yyyy`

you can also do custom formatting by using the `Custom` option and PHP `date`  `time` notation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

Comment: Thank you, @ckpepper02! I was trying to do that the hard way. ;-)